# See clipboard activity from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I'm working on a chrome extension. I need to see if the clipboard has been activated while on any page. The problem is it only works if the extension is open.

I've tried adding an event listener hoping that would be how I can do it but it didn't work.

```
bg.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  alert("hello");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: "clipboard has been activated" is an unusual term, what do you mean exactly by this?

Comment: I mean to see if anyone copied anything from the site. Like ctrl+c or right click copy

Comment: The listener should be inside a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) where you'll use `document` instead of `bg`.

Comment: yup that worked perfect! Thank you very much for your help!